# why is text hiding behind states in my D3 Map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image: Illinois is heartbroken]

Hi, I've nearly finished a map using d3js, but ran into a strange issue: some text elements are hidden underneath adjacent states. I tried setting the `z-index` of the text higher than that of the states. Does this have something to do with creating the arcs before the text? If so, my hands are tied because I am using `mouseover` event to display text. Please advise, I'm curious to know why the text is showing this way.

I've included the full code on Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lYPWOHPACjpEq7MymII2?p=preview
You can see the problem when mousing over Indiana and Illinois

Here's the code for creating the state boundaries and adding text with mouseover event:

```
var g = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(us.features)
    .enter()
    .append("g")

var allState = g.append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "state-boundary")
    .style("fill",function(d){console.log(d.properties.pdi);return "rgb("+ rad(d.properties.pdi) + ",0,0)"});

g.on("mouseover",function(){
    d3.select(this).append("text")
      .attr("class","states")
      .text(function(d){return d.properties.NAME})
      .attr("x",function(d){return path.centroid(d)[0]})
      .attr("y",function(d){return path.centroid(d)[1]})
      })
g.on("mouseout",function(){
    d3.select(".states")
    .remove()
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an SVG to create your map. In an SVG (which has no z-index), the drawing order is the most important thing to define what is on top and what is on bottom.

That being said, this is your problem: each text is being append on a `<g>` element, but some `<g>`s were painted before. Like this:

```
<g>
    <path "Illinois path here"></path>
</g>
<g>
    <path "Indiana path here"></path>
</g>
```

And then, when you hover over Illinois:

```
<g>
    <path "Illinois path here"></path>
    <text "Illinois text here"></path>
</g>
<g>
    <path "Indiana path here"></path><!--Indiana path over Illinois text!-->
</g>
```

Thus, the solution is very simple: just [raise](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_raise) the group:

```
d3.select(this).raise().append("text")
```

This is your updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EFwnO7BCHKeXvjtsIWeL?p=preview